# How to connect a web domain name purchased from Google domains to a website developed on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

How do I connect a web domain name I purchased from Google domains to a website developed on the Google app engine?

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())
```

Comment: Spelling and a little content.

Answer (score 2):

On *Settings* -> *Custom Domains* page:

https://console.developers.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project=&moduleId=default